# Any way to prevent a port from being used/listened to?

Tags: windows, networking

Say for some reason, on a Windows system I'm managing, I do not want any application to listen on a certain port, say for example 8000.
The effect would be when a user tries to run an application to listen on that port, for example, `python -m http.server 8000`, he gets the usual error saying `OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`. And when he checks if anything is already using that port using a command like `netstat -ano|findstr 8000` he wouldn't find anything.
It's kind of like reserving, like saying "no one is allowed to use this port, cause I might need to use it for important business".
How should I go about doing that? Does Windows support this natively? Do I need 3rd party software to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the 'netsh' command-line utility.
This will make 'reservation' of ports... Making them unbindable by unprivileged processes.

NETSH list reserved ports on ipv4 > tcp stack:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

NETSH reserve ports (template):

```
netsh int <ipv4|ipv6> Add excludedportrange [protocol=]tcp|udp [startport=]<integer> [numberofports=]<integer> [[store=]active|persistent]
```

EXAMPLE: NETSH, reserve port 8000 for ipv4 > tcp, use the command:

```
netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=8000 numberofports=1
```

By default port reservations are persistent across reboots.

In all case, i suggest you to read the [NETSH documentation and related usage and examples links](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh)

**If the above solution is not working, you may try it :**

- [windows-server reserve a port range by registry.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/reserve-a-range-of-ephemeral-ports)
- However, if you are running **Windows Server 2008**, you may experience issue with the functionality and you would need to install HOTFIX or update your system, [as explained here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-cannot-exclude-ports-by-using-the-reservedports-registry-key-in-windows-server-2008-or-in-windows-server-2008-r2-a68373fd-9f64-4bde-9d68-c5eded74ea35).

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: It seems after running `netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=8000 numberofports=1` myself and other users (I created a new non-admin user) are still able to bind to port 8000. Would you know why that is?  I'll go read the documentation again now and hopefully find the answer myself.

Comment: This is weird, because in my side (WIndows 10) it is working perfectly. I recommend you to: 1 - update your question by sharing me a screen capture of your 'netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp' command. 2- if you are runnnig under windows 2008, this feature may not work, and you would need to install an HOTFIX: [WS2008-hotfix-excludedportrange] (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-cannot-exclude-ports-by-using-the-reservedports-registry-key-in-windows-server-2008-or-in-windows-server-2008-r2-a68373fd-9f64-4bde-9d68-c5eded74ea35) link

Comment: I completed my answer. Hope it helps.